# How to resume Azure serverless SQL Server from pause

Tags: azure-sql-database

I created a serverless sql on azure and didn't use it for few weeks. Now when I go back to it, I found it's in Pause status.

But searching the azure dashboard, I can't find any way to resume it. When I google this topic, all result are talking about how to resume Dedicated SQL pool which appears to be a different thing.

How to bring it back online?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once the Azure Database is in pause status, it resumes automatically in the following conditions:

- Database connection
- database export or copy
- Viewing auditing records
- Viewing or applying performance recommendation
- Vulnerability assessment
- Modifying or viewing data masking rules
- View state for transparent data encryption
- Modification for serverless configuration such as max vCores, min vCores, or auto-pause delay

https://www.sqlshack.com/automatic-pause-and-resume-an-azure-sql-database/

Comment: you are right, it's back now. How long does it usually take to back online?

Comment: @CircleHsiao for this, I don't have a number. Don't expect it to be big (under a minute, probably)

Comment: I confirm @AlekseyVitsko, it takes maximum 1 minute

Answer (score 5):

How about the official documentation ?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/serverless-tier-overview

> Auto-resuming is triggered if any of the following conditions are true
> at any time:
>
> - Login Enabling/disabling threat detection settings at the database or    server level.
> - Modifying threat detection settings at the database or    server    level.
> - Adding, modifying, deleting, or viewing sensitivity    labels Viewing    auditing records.
> - Updating or viewing auditing policy.
> - Adding, modifying, deleting,or viewing data masking rules
> - Viewing state or status of transparent data encryption
> - Ad hoc (vulnurability) scans and periodic scans if enabled  Modifying or viewing query store settings
> - Viewing or applying performance recommendations
> - Application and verification of auto-tuning recommendations such as auto-indexing
> - Createdatabase as copy.
> - Export to a BACPAC file.
> - Synchronization between hub and member databases    that run on a configurable schedule or are performed manually Adding    new database
>   tags.
> - Changing max vCores, min vCores, or auto-pause    delay.
> - Using SSMS versions earlier than 18.1 and opening a new query    window for any database in the server will resume any auto-paused
>   database in the same server. This behavior does not occur if using
>   SSMS version 18.1 or later.
>
> The latency to auto-resume and auto-pause a serverless database is
> generally order of 1 minute to auto-resume and 1-10 minutes after the
> expiration of the delay period to auto-pause.

At first glance `Resume-AzSqlDatabase` looks promising, but it will fail. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.sql/resume-azsqldatabase says only

> The Resume-AzSqlDatabase cmdlet works only on Azure SQL Data Warehouse databases. This operation is not supported on Azure SQL Database Basic, Standard and Premium editions.

Comment: Have put in a feature request:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/19212